# How to pass a data by systemcall to DRAMctrl in Gem5?

Tags: python, c++, simulator, gem5

I want to pass a specific data to DRAMCtrl in gem5 by using the syscall. if anyone ever implemented any relevant method on gem5?

Comment: Hi, do you mean a m5op instead os syscall? What information do you want to pass to DRAMctrl? Also post on the mailing list.

Comment: Hi, yes. I want to transfer the information in the c program to the DRAMCtrl of gem5 by systemcall because I want to do the experiment of Computing in Memory. I am new to gem5, so I am not sure how to start. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Aron there might be better methods, but using m5ops will work for sure. First just play with them a little bit on syscall emulation, e.g. `m5 dumpstats`, here are some pointers: https://cirosantilli.com/linux-kernel-module-cheat/#m5ops Then just grep a bit the source code and you'll easily see how they are set up, and then just copy one of them to create your own.